# How do I handle multiple files in a form without knowing the amount of them?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, file

I'm creating a website for a **printing store**, and when adding a product to the cart, it can't just add it to the cart, it needs some information from the user (for example, a **pdf** or an **image**).
This information varies from one product to the other, and is defined in **Product.InfoNeeded** which is a list of **Info**s (a class) which has a the exact type of information this product needs.
Some products need just one file, some need 2, and some need 3, so I created such a form:

```
@model xyz.ViewModels.CartItemFormViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "xyz";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "CartItems"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the following errors:")

    var index = 0;

    foreach (var info in Model.InfoNeeded)
    {
        index++;
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label(info.Label)
            <input type="file" id="@index" name="file_@index" class="form-control-file">
        </div>
    }

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    </div>
}
```

This is the **ViewModel**:

```
public class CartItemFormViewModel
{
    public CartItem CartItem { get; set; }

    public List<Info> InfoNeeded { get; set; }

    public CartItemFormViewModel(int productId, List<Info> infoNeeded)
    {
        CartItem = new CartItem(productId);

        InfoNeeded = infoNeeded;
    }
}
```

This is the **Add** Action:

```
public ActionResult Add(int id)
    {
        var infoNeeded = _context.Products
            .Include(p => p.InfoNeeded)
            .Single(p => p.Id == id)
            .InfoNeeded;

        var viewModel = new CartItemFormViewModel(id, infoNeeded);

        return View("CartItemForm", viewModel);
    }
```

Now, how do I get these files here by the **Save** action?

```
public ActionResult Save()
    {
        return Content("");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your model to include something like this

```
public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> CartFiles { set; get; }
```

This way you can intercept all submitted files in for and process them. This is of course one part. Problem begins when you are trying multiupload in form. I have tried many plugins so far and dropzone was the only one that was able to process multiple files in submit form without problems like deleting and re adding files.

In case you choose dropzone this is optimal configuration when using form submit.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var options = {
    paramName: "CartFiles",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    autoDiscover: false,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    thumbnailWidth: 250,
    thumbnailHeight: 250,
    dictRemoveFile: "@Resources.Strings.Delete",
    previewsContainer: '#dropzonePreview',
    maxFiles: 5 ), <-- remove this if unlimited
    clickable: '.dropzone',
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.pdf",
};

var dropZone = new Dropzone("form#productForm", options);
```

Edit:

You can read about dropzone [here DropzoneJS is an open source library that provides drag’n’drop file uploads with image previews.](https://www.dropzonejs.com/)

I am not able to completely review your code, based on snippets you provided, but basically there is no need to loop and crate input files manually.

Example pseudocode

View - I am using ajax to update controller and return feedback to user and view. Of course its up to you.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "CartItems", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnBegin = "OnBegin", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }, new { @id = "ajaxForm", @class = "was-validated", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="row">
                <label>Please drop your files here</label>
                <div class="col-md-12 dropzone">
                    <div class="dropzone-previews" id="dropzonePreview">
                        <i class="icon-file-upload icon-5x absolute-center text-muted"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group mt-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input class="btn btn-inverse btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" name="inputSubmit" type="submit" value="@Resources.Strings.Save" title='@Resources.Strings.Save' />
                    <input class="btn btn-green cancel" id="btnCancel" name="inputCancel" type="button" value="@Resources.Strings.Cancel" title='@Resources.Strings.Cancel' />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


<script src="~/../dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var options = {
        paramName: "CartFiles",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        autoDiscover: false,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 5,
        thumbnailWidth: 250,
        thumbnailHeight: 250,
        dictRemoveFile: "@Resources.Strings.Delete",
        previewsContainer: '#dropzonePreview',
        clickable: '.dropzone',
        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png",
    };

        var dropZone = new Dropzone("form#ajaxForm", options);

        dropZone.element.querySelector("input[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation(); 
            // if dropzone has file process them, if not send empty array
            if (dropZone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
                dropZone.processQueue();
            } else {
                $("#ajaxForm").submit();
            }
        });
});
```

Controller part

```
public JsonResult Save()
{
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
       {
          for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
             {
                [YourModel].CartFiles.Append(Request.Files[i]);
             }
          // do whatever is needed to save files
       }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean **Multi upload in form**, and can you please explain more what's **Dropzone** and what is it's purpose.

Comment: Please review my question, read through the **view**, notice how I do structure my **file form fields** in a loop.